# I want to print a document usin c# . But my printer interpeat that i want to print with phografer paper but i want to print A4 normal paper

Tags: c#, printing

```
//Button print

printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
printDocument1.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
DialogResult result = printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result==DialogResult.OK)
{
    printDocument1.Print ();
}


private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)

e.Graphics.DrawString("Nome Equipamento:  ", new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 210));

e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Text, new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, new Point(25, 250));
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. I only hacked this down without testing and I added no error handling code. It assumes your printer supports printing A4. But you should get the idea.

```
        PaperSize search;
        foreach (PaperSize item in printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes)
        {
            if (item.Kind == PaperKind.A4)
            {
                search = item;
                break;
            }
        }

        printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = search;
        printDocument1.Print();
```

Alternatively you can create your own paper size:

```
        printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = 
                new PaperSize("My A4", A4width, A4height);
```